# only single events showing per day with Json Request

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having a problem where only 1 event is showing per day.

My init code is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        events: "/cal/get",
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }

    });
```

and my json code is:

```
[{"id":"11","title":"2053","start":"2011-12-23T11:00:00","end":"2011-12-23T12:05:00","allDay":false},{"id":"13","title":"2057","start":"2011-12-17T23:00:00","end":"2011-12-18T0:05:00","allDay":false},{"id":"9","title":"2060","start":"2011-12-17T20:45:00","end":"2011-12-17T21:45:00","allDay":false},{"id":"15","title":"2059","start":"2011-12-17T2:00:00","end":"2011-12-17T3:30:00","allDay":false},{"id":"14","title":"2058","start":"2011-12-17T1:30:00","end":"2011-12-17T3:30:00","allDay":false},{"id":"12","title":"2052","start":"2011-12-16T15:15:00","end":"2011-12-16T16:15:00","allDay":false},{"id":"8","title":"2056","start":"2011-12-07T9:45:00","end":"2011-12-07T10:30:00","allDay":false}]
```

but all I ever get is a single event for each day.  I've read through the documentation and answers, and still can't come to a conclusion.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does your question start with `).`? You know there's no hurry, right? You can take all the time you need before posting in order to ensure that your question makes sense. You're much more likely to get help if people understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamps of your events are not correct.

Take December 17th for example.

```
{"id":"9","title":"2060","start":"2011-12-17T20:45:00","end":"2011-12-17T21:45:00","allDay":false},
{"id":"15","title":"2059","start":"2011-12-17T2:00:00","end":"2011-12-17T3:30:00","allDay":false},
{"id":"14","title":"2058","start":"2011-12-17T1:30:00","end":"2011-12-17T3:30:00","allDay":false},
```

`2:00:00` is not a valid timestamp, it needs to have a leading 0 if you meant 2 a.m., or it needs to be `14:00:00` if you meant 2 p.m.

Same goes for the end time, 3:30:00 needs to either be 03:30:00 or 15:30:00.